# about Graph2GO main.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

https://github.com/yanzhanglab/Graph2GO

Run the main program

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Namespace(data_path='../../data/', dropout=0, epochs_ppi=80, epochs_simi=60, graphs=['combined', 'similarity'], hidden1=800, hidden2=400, lr=0.001, model='gcn_vae', only_gcn=0, ppi_attributes=6, save_results=1, simi_attributes=5, species='human', supervised='nn', thr_combined=0.3, thr_evalue=0.0001, weight_decay=0)
loading features...
#############################
Training combined
loading data...
generating features...
loading graph...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/Graph2GO-master210805/src/Graph2GO/main.py", line 143, in <module>
    train(args)
  File "D:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/Graph2GO-master210805/src/Graph2GO/main.py", line 30, in train
    embeddings = train_gcn(features, adj, args, graph)
  File "D:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\Graph2GO-master210805\src\Graph2GO\trainGcn.py", line 23, in train_gcn
    adj_orig = adj_orig - sp.dia_matrix((adj_orig.diagonal()[np.newaxis, :], [0]), shape=adj_orig.shape)
  File "D:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\Graph2GO-master210805\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 533, in diagonal
    raise ValueError("k exceeds matrix dimensions")
ValueError: k exceeds matrix dimensions
```

However, I found no out of range debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a silly mistake by the author while making a copy of the sparse matrix, the easy fix is that in trainGcn.py in line 22 make sure you are copying the matrix replace line 22 with

```
adj_orig = adj_train.copy()
```

I have submitted a PR to the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/yanzhanglab/Graph2GO/compare/master...rietesh:patch-1)

Comment: I useadj_orig = adj_train.copy()Replaced line 22, but still reported the same error?

Comment: Is this no different from the original line 23?

Comment: ```adj_orig = adj_orig - sp.dia_matrix((adj_orig.diagonal()[np.newaxis, :], np.array([0])), shape=adj_orig.shape)``` add np.array([0])

Comment: thanks,but still reported the same error...In addition, I found him prompt from trainSVM import train_svm```Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/Graph2GO-master210805/src/Graph2GO/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from trainSVM import train_svm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trainSVM'```

Comment: you need to comment out that line, delete it

Comment: After running according to Readme```cd src/Graph2GO
python main.py``````the following error is reported, ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 143, in <module>
    train(args)
  File "main.py", line 23, in train
    uniprot = pd.read_pickle(os.path.join(args.data_path, args.species, "features.pkl"))
  File "D:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\Graph2GO-master\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 169, in read_pickle
    f, fh = get_handle(fp_or_buf, "rb", compression=compression, is_text=False)```

Comment: and```File "D:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\Graph2GO-master\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 499, in get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../data/human\\features.pkl'```but this file exists